# Fancybox button helper won't display

Tags: button, fancybox

I haven't been able to get fancybox to display the button helpers. I (am pretty sure) I am loading the css & javascript files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=2.0.4" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=2.0.4"></script>
```

Here's my FancyBox js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        nextEffect : 'fade',
        prevEffect : 'fade',
        openEffect : 'fade',
        closeEffect : 'fade',
        closeBtn : 'true',
        loop : 'false',
        arrows : 'true',
        nextClick : 'true',
        mouseWheel : 'true',
        helpers     : { 
        title   : { type : 'inside' },
        buttons : {},
        }
    }); 

});
```

And my image HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="comic" href="http://clpmag.org/admin/rdb/slideshow/gliddencomic/01-glidden-comic.jpg" title=""><img src="http://clpmag.org/admin/rdb/slideshow/gliddencomic/01-glidden-comic.jpg" /></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="comic" href="http://clpmag.org/admin/rdb/slideshow/gliddencomic/02-glidden-comic.jpg" title="" style="display:none;"><img src="http://clpmag.org/admin/rdb/slideshow/gliddencomic/02-glidden-comic.jpg" width="470px"/></a>
```

But in the fancybox on the article page, http://clpmag.org/article.php?article=The-Rollerbladers-of-Suleimaniya_00339 , I don't see the button helpers at the top of the screen.  Any ideas?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Fancybox's buttons are inside of this container:

```
<div id="fancybox-buttons" class="top">
```

which uses this `css` rule:

```
#fancybox-buttons.top {
    top: 10px;
}
```

but you have this other `css` rule

```
.top {
    margin-top: -80px;
}
```

in your file http://clpmag.org/css/n_global.css (line 326), which overrides the fancybox rule and displaces the buttons out of the visible area of the viewport

So you either rename the `class` '*top*' or use some specificity like:

```
#parent .top {}
```

BTW, it's not a good idea to set general css rules like

```
a {
    color: #3770CA;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

because that will affect also to other jQuery plugins you may want to use .... again some specificity or the use of classes will be recommended like

```
#wrapper a {
        color: #3770CA;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change Line 8 in jquery.fancybox-buttons.css

```
#fancybox-buttons.top {
   top: 75px;
}
```

And it'll be fixed, also make sure yo add this rule in your own CSS file:

```
#fancybox-buttons ul li {
     list-style-type: none; list-style-type: none; 
}
```